# web.py db.insert function throw error : <type 'exceptions.TypeError'> : 'long' object is unsubscriptable

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database, web.py

I have a database(mysql) table named foo, and its primary key is bigint type, and auto increment, 
I write the following codes to insert a record and get the record's primary key

```
q = db.insert('foo', name='bob', age=2, _test=True)
print q
```

this record has been insert into the table, but I got the following error:

> type 'exceptions.TypeError' : 'long' object is unsubscriptable

Can you help me what should I do ?

Answer (score 1):

You get the `TypeError: '<type>' object is not subscriptable` error when you try to use the `__getitem__` interface to an object that doesn't support it. That normally looks like this `container[...]`.

Take a look at the full traceback. Somewhere, you should see an object being accessed that way. Since you haven't shown the full traceback or the rest of your code, I can't tell you where.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is in the print q
It is not mentionned in the doc of web.py

```
>>> db = DB(None, {})
>>> q = db.insert('foo', name='bob', age=2, created=SQLLiteral('NOW()'), _test=True)
>>> q
<sql: "INSERT INTO foo (age, name, created) VALUES (2, 'bob', NOW())">
>>> q.query()
'INSERT INTO foo (age, name, created) VALUES (%s, %s, NOW())'
>>> q.values()
[2, 'bob']
```